# GregorianCalendar shows odd values?

Tags: java, android, calendar

Ok.

```
calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
```

returns the index of the current month. So for example if this line of code were to be executed right now, it'd return 7 for August.

However

```
calendar.get(Calendar.AUGUST);
```

aswell as

```
calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH); in april
```

returns 3?

This makes it rather hard for me to get the correct date values depending on my development context.

Can someone shed some light upon me why this is as is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't be using `calendar.get(CALENDAR.AUGUST)` - that's using a constant representing a *value* as if it were a constant representing a *field type*. It's unfortunate that the `Calendar` API is so poorly designed to let this happen, IMO, but you really need to understand why it's not meaningful.

A date in April returns 3 for the same reason that a date in August returns 7 - the months are 0-based in `Calendar`. I'm surprised that you were happy for August to return 7 but be confused by April returning 3...

Anyway, from the docs for [`Calendar.MONTH`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#MONTH):

> Field number for get and set indicating the month. This is a calendar-specific value. The first month of the year in the Gregorian and Julian calendars is JANUARY which is 0; the last depends on the number of months in a year.

I would *strongly* advise you to look into [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net) if you're doing anything even slightly non-trivial in Java with dates and times - it's a *much* saner and more expressive API than `Date`/`Calendar`.

Comment: I guess it's time to look into third party libraries. Thanks for the info.

Comment: @Da_smokes: I hadn't noticed that you're on Android - that will make it slightly harder to use Joda Time. (In particular, for the sake of space and time you may want to use a cut down set of time zones.) However, it's definitely possible. Alternatively, the built-in classes do work, you just need to be careful.

Comment: What i basically want to do is to get a datestring in the format of yyyyMMddHH from a static timezone, at all times. And these lines seems to do the trick at the moment:

DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyyMMddHH");
  DateTime dt = new DateTime();
  DateTimeZone ge = DateTimeZone.forID("Europe/Stockholm");
  fmt.withZone(ge);
  print(dt.toString(fmt));

Comment: @Da_smokes: Yes - Joda Time's lovely. But it can take a while to start up on Android, I believe. Look around and see if anyone's done a tailored Android version.

Comment: @Da_smokes: I've just noticed that you're not using the result of `fmt.withZone` - you should have `fmt = fmt.withZone(ge);` or something like that. The formatters themselves are immutable.

Comment: Cheers, didnt notice, as it didnt throw an error in the syntax i assumed it was a setter :)

Answer (score 1):

Calendar.get() takes an integer with values such as 2 to request the Month or 7 to request the day of week. MONTH and DAY_OF_WEEK are final ints provided to let you specify those values more readably.

The final int AUGUST also happens to have a value 7, (same as DAY_OF_WEEK) but is not intended to be passed to get(), it's just a useful int corresponding to the value returned as the month in August (Java Months being zero based.)

Hence it is not meaningful to pass AUGUST to get(). This confusion is a relic of the pre-enum Java days. Had the Calendar class been designed to use enums it would all have been clearer.

Answer (score 1):

This is completely unrelated to Android. `java.util.Calendar` has a bad interface for sure, but you are using it wrong too. `calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)` returns the current month where January =0, `calendar.get(Calendar.AUGUST)` is meaningless. The const value for `AUGUST` happens to be 7 which is the same as `Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK`, so you are effectively getting the day of week (TUESDAY). In short, don't do that.